# Delete from using multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-delete

I have a subquery that returns a subset of values from a table like:

```
CASEID      CLASS   date
-2342055    25      2010-08-05 15:26:28.530
-2342032    20      2011-08-31 11:57:56.890
-2342032    21      2011-08-31 11:58:33.180
-2342032    24      2011-08-31 11:59:11.680
-2342032    25      2011-08-31 11:59:48.480
```

Now, I want to delete from the table on these three values. So, delete the row which has the caseid, class & date values like those returned in the subquery.

Comment: What is the `select` statement that returns these rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your sql into a `cte` and then delete FROM your_cte.

```
WITH MyCTE 
AS 
(
 --insert sub query here...
)

DELETE FROM MyCTE
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it was a good quick way of solving my problem.